# Parallel Tasks Calling Static function

Tags: c#, task

I Have issue with parllel Tasks 
My Code

```
namespace ITDevices  
{  
    using System.Linq;  
    using System.Collections.Generic;  
    using System.Threading.Tasks;  
    using System;

    /*Device Modal*/
    public class Device
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MAC { get; set; }
    }

    /*Entry Class*/
    class Program
    {
        static async void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Task<Device>> Tasks = new List<Task<Device>>();

            for(int i=2;i==0;i--)
            {
                Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew<Device>(
                    ()=> {
                            Device free = Helper.GetFreeDevice();
                            return free;
                        }
                    ));       
            }
            await Task.WhenAll(Tasks.ToArray());
            foreach(Task<Device> item in Tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Result.IP);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    /*Devices Helper*/
    static class Helper
    {


        public static List<Device> UsedDevices = new List<Device>();

        public static Device GetFreeDevice()
        {
             List<Device> OnlineDevices = new List<Device>()
            {
                new Device { IP="192.168.1.15",Name="PerryLabtop",MAC="AC:DS:F2:CC:2D:7A"},
                new Device { IP="192.168.1.20",Name="MAYA-PC",MAC="7D:E9:2C:FF:E7:2D"},
                new Device { IP="192.168.1.2",Name="server",MAC="D8:C2:A4:DC:E5:3A"}
            };

            Device FreeDevice = OnlineDevices.Where(x => !UsedDevices.Contains(x)).SingleOrDefault();
            if (FreeDevice != null)
                UsedDevices.Add(FreeDevice);
            return FreeDevice;
        }
    }
}

//Output   
//192.168.1.15  
//192.168.1.15

But expected output must be
//192.168.1.15
//192.168.1.20
```

When debugging the project

all tasks execute GetFreeDevice() function at same time line by line 
I need to make tasks wait while current GetFreeDevice() function execution done .. or any thing helpful

THANKS ALL

Comment: Then don't use tasks if you need sequential execution, just call the `GetFreeDevice()` inside a loop.

Comment: Having `static async void Main(string[] args)` does not work the way you think it works. you can't make the `Main` function async.

Answer (score 4):

Several problems must be solved to make it work properly:

1. You probably reversed condition in `for` loop, because *int i = 2; i == 0; i--* will do nothing. Replace `i == 0` with `i != 0`
2. `async` Main method doesn't make sense (see for example [this blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html)) and actually doesn't even compile in Visual Studio. To fix this, you can for example wait for tasks to complete synchronously (use `.Wait()` instead of `await`)
3. To prevent multiple threads to run *GetFreeDevice()*  method simultaneously, simply place lock around code that uses shared objects - which is whole method body in your case.
4. Because you create new list of *OnlineDevices* each time *GetFreeDevice()* method is called, *UsedDevices.Contains(x)* will not work as expected. By default, objects are compared by their reference. So *.Contains(x)* will compare *Device* objects in *UsedDevices* list (which were put there in one of previous calls) with newly created *Device* objects, which will never be equal (references of these object will be different despite *IP*, *Name* and *MAC* being the same). To fix this, you could either override *Equals()* and *GetHashCode()* methods on *Device* class, or (as i did) create just one static list of *Device* objects.
5. You must replace *SingleOrDefault()* with *FirstOrDefault()*. With *SingleOrDefault()*, program would throw exception if there is more than one unused device, while *FirstOrDefault()* will take first unused device even if there is more than one.

Full source code with all proposed fixes:

```
namespace ITDevices
{
    /*Device Modal*/
    public class Device
    {
        public string IP { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string MAC { get; set; }
    }

    /*Entry Class*/
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Task<Device>> Tasks = new List<Task<Device>>();

            for (int i = 2; i != 0; i--)
            {
                Tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew<Device>(
                    () => {
                        Device free = Helper.GetFreeDevice();
                        return free;
                    }
                    ));
            }
            Task.WhenAll(Tasks.ToArray()).Wait();
            foreach (Task<Device> item in Tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Result.IP);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    /*Devices Helper*/
    static class Helper
    {
        public static List<Device> UsedDevices = new List<Device>();

        static List<Device> OnlineDevices = new List<Device>()
        {
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.15",Name="PerryLabtop",MAC="AC:DS:F2:CC:2D:7A"},
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.20",Name="MAYA-PC",MAC="7D:E9:2C:FF:E7:2D"},
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.2",Name="server",MAC="D8:C2:A4:DC:E5:3A"}
        };

        static Object LockObject = new Object();

        public static Device GetFreeDevice()
        {
            lock (LockObject)
            {
                Device FreeDevice = OnlineDevices.Where(x => !UsedDevices.Contains(x)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (FreeDevice != null)
                    UsedDevices.Add(FreeDevice);
                return FreeDevice;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This very helpful thanks some errors because this is virtual code to explain what i need and real code is very complex

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
public static Device GetFreeDevice()
    {
         List<Device> OnlineDevices = new List<Device>()
        {
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.15",Name="PerryLabtop",MAC="AC:DS:F2:CC:2D:7A"},
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.20",Name="MAYA-PC",MAC="7D:E9:2C:FF:E7:2D"},
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.2",Name="server",MAC="D8:C2:A4:DC:E5:3A"}
        };

        Device FreeDevice = OnlineDevices.Where(x => !UsedDevices.Contains(x)).SingleOrDefault();
        if (FreeDevice != null)
            lock (UsedDevices)
                UsedDevices.Add(FreeDevice);
        return FreeDevice;
    }
```

------------------------ UPDATE

try:

```
public static Device GetFreeDevice()
    {
         List<Device> OnlineDevices = new List<Device>()
        {
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.15",Name="PerryLabtop",MAC="AC:DS:F2:CC:2D:7A"},
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.20",Name="MAYA-PC",MAC="7D:E9:2C:FF:E7:2D"},
            new Device { IP="192.168.1.2",Name="server",MAC="D8:C2:A4:DC:E5:3A"}
        };

        lock (UsedDevices)
        {
            Device FreeDevice = OnlineDevices.Where(x => !UsedDevices.Contains(x)).SingleOrDefault();
            if (FreeDevice != null)
                UsedDevices.Add(FreeDevice);
        }
        return FreeDevice;
    }
```

Comment: You have to lock write **and** read to UsedDevices in this case